# iOS application, Table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

can someone help me please! I'm using Xcode version 6.4 to develop an application using swift language ,I want to retrieve data "children information" from parse and store the data in a table also I want to edit the "child information " after select a child from the table ,this is my code when I run it Simulator screen become black after displaying the project name

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tblchild:UITableView!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var childQuery=PFQuery(className:"Child")
        //run the query

        childQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success,error) -> Void in
            if let objects=success{
                for object in objects{
                    var str:String?{

                        if let name=object["childName"]{return "\(name)" }
                        return ""
                        }
                      var name=object["childName"]
                        var unwrappedName=""
                        if let name=name{

                            unwrappedName="\(name)"
                        }

                    }
                    self.tblchild.reloadData()


                }//end loop

            }//end the first if



        }//end of the find objects

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    //override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
       // tblchild.reloadData();
    //  }



    //UITableViewDataSource
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
       return child.children.count
    }
    //bulding cell
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell:UITableViewCell=UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Default")
        cell.textLabel?.text=child.children[indexPath.row].name

        return cell

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know parse but I recommend making sure your table view is wired up correctly before doing anything else. First comment out `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` and return `0` from `numberOfRowsInSection`. When you run, a blank table view should appear. If that works then create a simple model, like an array with one string, return `myArray.count` in `numberOfRowsInSection` and adjust `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` accordingly. When you run you should see your string and you can be confident the table view is wired up correctly. Then go from there.

Comment: The code looks pretty confusing, no offense. What is the computed variable `str` in the middle of the completion block for? And please avoid the optional binding syntax `if let name = name`. It's supposed to be `if let unwrappedName = name`

Comment: thanks a lot Murray & Vadian ,,Murray black simulator still appears                   Vadian can you please  till me how to retrieve and store data step by step please

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Parse` but usually you retrieve data – mostly an array of dictionaries –  in the background and in the completion block you have to update your data source before reloading the table. In your case the `child.children` object is supposed to be updated.

Comment: You are also calling reloadData off the main thread, I suspect this is causing issues as well.

Comment: There is no use worrying about parse until the tableview is wired up. I recommend following this tutorial: https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/